# Android Tooltip menu item style

Tags: java, android, styling, android-toolbar

I can't find anything on the google and stackoverflow so I had to ask. 
I have menu on Toolbar:

```
<item
        android:icon="@drawable/help_button_selector"
        android:title="@string/Menu_Toolbar_Help"
        android:id="@+id/MENU_HELP"
        app:showAsAction="always"/>
```

When user long press icon, system shows tooltip (popup/context menu) with title. However on most devices it has black border (like in Toast). Is there any way to style this border/background? I have already created style for toolbar theme and popup, but I can't find a proper item name.

Comment: Visit this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36267859/android-tooltips-on-menuitem?answertab=votes#tab-top

Answer (score 2):

1.- You can follow this post to create your ToolTip [link](http://www.londatiga.net/it/how-to-create-quickaction-dialog-in-android/)

2.-You can do this to show a Toast as a ToolTip, then you can customize it as you want.

```
    view.setOnLongClickListener(new OnLongClickListener() {
    public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
        Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), "I'm a ToolTip", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return true;
    }
}
```

Hope it helps :)

Comment: I upvoted because using Toast class is fine and simple, no library required. I don't know why someone downvoted, my only guess is the person does not understand it or the posted answer, too bad.

Comment: If you want a tooltip like toast than the answer is ok. However still on some devices the black border is showing. I know how to make toast like tooltip with custom view. I don't know how to solve the bug when strange border shows on tooltip toast.
Yours solution is not working correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Use below link to customize your Action Bar:
http://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/

open url -> GoTo Android Action Bar Style Generator -> Select the options  -> click DOWNLOAD.ZIP -> Copy all the componets into their correspondence folders -> In your styles.xml file remove all the code and copy all the code of styles_**.xml file and delete this file.

Answer (score 0):

Menu tooltip

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.menu_skip) {
        View view = findViewById(R.id.menu_skip);
        Tooltip.make(this, new Tooltip.Builder(101)
            .anchor(view, Tooltip.Gravity.BOTTOM)
            .closePolicy(mClosePolicy, 5000)
            .text("Tooltip on a TabLayout child...Tooltip on a TabLayout       child...")
            .fadeDuration(200)
            .fitToScreen(true)
            .activateDelay(2000)
            .withCallback(this)
            .floatingAnimation(Tooltip.AnimationBuilder.DEFAULT)
            .showDelay(400)
            .build()
    ).show();
    return true;
}
return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
```

}

[Visit more](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37880587/6479222)