# Android Tooltips on MenuItem

Tags: android, android-fragments, tooltip

I'm trying to show a tooltip on a `MenuItem`.

I'm using this library: **`compile 'com.github.xizzhu:simple-tool-tip:0.5.0'`** from this Maven repository:  **`maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }`**.
I'm getting the view for the `MenuItem`, to use it as an anchor for the `ToolTip` but it is launching a `nullPointerException` in the `toolTipView.show()` method.
When I debug the app, the `View` item is correct.
If i replace the `View` item with the floating button fab, it works perfectly.

At some point, it worked, but the `ToolTip` position was wrong, it appears on the left top corner of the screen, instead of the right position, which would be at bottom of `View` item.

Note: I'm creating the `ToolTip` inside `OnCreateOptionsMenu()` because `OnViewCreated()` run before this method, so I have to do it there.

Here is where it happens, if you need any other piece of code I can upload it.

**Menu:**

```
<menu
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tooltipproto="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_settings"
        tooltipproto:actionViewClass="android.widget.ImageButton"
        android:title="@string/action_settings"
        tooltipproto:showAsAction="always" />

</menu>
```

**Fragment:**

```
package com.tooltipproto;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import com.github.xizzhu.simpletooltip.ToolTip;
import com.github.xizzhu.simpletooltip.ToolTipView;

public class ShowFragment extends Fragment{

    View item;
    FloatingActionButton fab;

    public ShowFragment(){
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        MenuItem menuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_settings);
        item = menuItem.getActionView();

        ToolTip toolTip = new ToolTip.Builder()
                .withText("Simple Tool Tip!")
                .withTextSize(50)
                .withPadding(10,10,10,10)
                .withCornerRadius(10)
                .build();
        final ToolTipView toolTipView = new ToolTipView.Builder(getActivity())
                .withAnchor(item)
                .withToolTip(toolTip)
                .withGravity(Gravity.BOTTOM)
                .build();
        toolTipView.show();
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup parent, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Defines the xml file for the fragment
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);
        fab = (FloatingActionButton) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
        });
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment, parent, false);
    }


}
```

Answer (score 2):

Method 1:

First create custom toolbar

Tooltip library link [Visit](https://github.com/sephiroth74/android-target-tooltip)

activity_login.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:banner="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
android:background="@mipmap/background"
tools:context="com.and.postanads.LoginActivity">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:text="SKIP"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
            android:id="@+id/txt_skip"
            android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
            android:layout_gravity="right"/>

    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

LoginActivity.java

```
public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements Tooltip.Callback {


private Tooltip.ClosePolicy mClosePolicy = Tooltip.ClosePolicy.TOUCH_ANYWHERE_CONSUME;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    Tooltip.dbg = true;

    TextView textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txt_skip);
    Tooltip.make(this, new Tooltip.Builder(101)
                .anchor(textView, Tooltip.Gravity.BOTTOM)
                .closePolicy(mClosePolicy, 5000)
                .text("Tooltip on a TabLayout child...Tooltip on a TabLayout child...")
                .withStyleId(R.style.ToolTipLayoutDefaultStyle_CustomFont)
                .fadeDuration(200)
                .fitToScreen(true)
                .activateDelay(2000)
                .withCallback(this)
                .floatingAnimation(Tooltip.AnimationBuilder.DEFAULT)
                .showDelay(400)
                .build()
        ).show();
    }
}
```

[Sample image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xzbLj.png)

Method 2:

Using Menu_item

menu_login.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
<item
    android:id="@+id/menu_skip"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    android:title="Skip"
    app:showAsAction="always"/>
</menu>
```

LoginActivity.java

```
public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements Tooltip.Callback {
private Tooltip.ClosePolicy mClosePolicy = Tooltip.ClosePolicy.TOUCH_ANYWHERE_CONSUME;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    Tooltip.dbg = true;
}
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_login, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.menu_skip) {
        View view = findViewById(R.id.menu_skip);
        Tooltip.make(this, new Tooltip.Builder(101)
                .anchor(view, Tooltip.Gravity.BOTTOM)
                .closePolicy(mClosePolicy, 5000)
                .text("Tooltip on a TabLayout child...Tooltip on a TabLayout child...")
                .fadeDuration(200)
                .fitToScreen(true)
                .activateDelay(2000)
                .withCallback(this)
                .floatingAnimation(Tooltip.AnimationBuilder.DEFAULT)
                .showDelay(400)
                .build()
        ).show();
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
}
```

Comment: I am using the menu tooltip example. Can you tell how do I use this tooltip for menu items in onCreate() of the activity?